# Flutter How to extend image in appbar?

Tags: flutter

I have this flutter page
[image]

I want this flowers image background to go all over the app bar as well with text MyProfile with other app bar buttons such as drawer and search button overlaying it.

Here is code as of now

```
Container(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  overflow: Overflow.visible,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 200.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        'https://timelinecovers.pro/facebook-cover/download/stunning-little-flowers-facebook-cover.jpg'))),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 100.0,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 190.0,
                        width: 190.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://static.displate.com/280x392/displate/2020-06-20/97526a531e9ff32c26f7752ebc926941_07a032cb55575a397e6ba8c98804ad43.jpgD'),
                            ),
                            border:
                                Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 6.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this by setting:

- `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` property in `Scaffold` widget.
- `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` and set `elevation: 0.0` in `AppBar` widget to make it fully transparent.

> If true, and an appBar is specified, then the height of the body is
> extended to include the height of the app bar and the top of the body
> is aligned with the top of the app bar.
>
> This is useful if the app bar's AppBar.backgroundColor is not
> completely opaque.

Source: [extendBodyBehindAppBar property from Flutter Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBodyBehindAppBar.html)

After this, adjust the `height` for:

- background image
- profile image

I copied your code and adjust it with the above solution, see the example below:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        leading: Icon(Icons.list),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                'https://timelinecovers.pro/facebook-cover/download/stunning-little-flowers-facebook-cover.jpg'))),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 180.0,
              child: Container(
                height: 190.0,
                width: 190.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://static.displate.com/280x392/displate/2020-06-20/97526a531e9ff32c26f7752ebc926941_07a032cb55575a397e6ba8c98804ad43.jpgD'),
                    ),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 6.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The `overflow` property of the Stack widget has been deprecated and removed in the latest versions of Flutter. Instead, you can use the `clipBehavior` property to specify how to clip the children of the Stack. `clipBehavior: Clip.none` should do the work here.

Answer (score 1):

some change on your code and result:

[image]

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 240.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                'https://timelinecovers.pro/facebook-cover/download/stunning-little-flowers-facebook-cover.jpg'))),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                width: width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){}),
                        Text('My Profile',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 22),),
                      ],
                    ),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications,color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){}),
                  ],
                ),
                height: 52,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 120.0,
              child: Container(
                height: 190.0,
                width: 190.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://static.displate.com/280x392/displate/2020-06-20/97526a531e9ff32c26f7752ebc926941_07a032cb55575a397e6ba8c98804ad43.jpgD'),
                    ),
                    border:
                    Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 6.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));

  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html) property of the Scaffold widget in Flutter. It will do what you want. You might have to resize things a bit. And maybe, make the AppBar color as transparent.